# How can you repair damaged sound file?

Tags: audio, mp3, wav, soundfile

I have a problem with my wav file. We played with our band (@bataty on instagram)in a club and we asked soundman to record the audio of our show. He gave us a record in wav but we cant play it anywhere.
Is the file damaged? Can somebody help me please?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=11ODe-3MUOIkbDomzNBnzt3DnSTr9j8qx

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it isn't related to software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your audio file isn't broken.  It plays fine.  It's just silent.

Your sound tech made a mistake and didn't record anything but silence.